# Proccess all my scss file from each component in Angular 4 like in Ionic

Tags: angular, sass, ionic2

I was working Ionic 3 and now I'm working in Angular 4 project. I generated the project with 'ng new myproject style=scss'.

I found that the only scss that work by default, its 'style.scss'.
How can I include all scss created by ng g component example automatically like work Ionic ? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`ng new myproject --style 'scss'` will do the trick

Or set the default style on an existing project:

```
ng set defaults.styleExt scss
```

[Docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli#usage)

Comment: I found my solution updating ng-cli and creating a new project like you said me, I should have tried this the first time. Thank you for your helping me.